# floobits Sublime Text 3 - SSL CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1124)

Tags: ssl, openssl, sublimetext3

Edit 1: I am using the floobits plugin (latest release), uninstalled and installed again from the package manager. I am not getting a traceback but an error window with the following error message:  Unable to join workspace. CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1124).

Edit 2: I had tried the Package Control Upgrade package and Staisfy Dependencies, but that did not help fix it.
I was able to fix it (answer below).

I have been stuck on this issue for days now. When I try to connect to a floobits workspace in sublime text, I get the error message that CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1124).
I searched about this a lot but I don't know what's wrong anymore.

I started by upgrading certifi and pip itself.
Then I read somewhere that I should check if OpenSSl(and the requests library of py) and cURL can open the URL (floobits.com) since the workspace is hosted there. curl returned no errors but OpenSSL (and requests) wasn't able to verify, gave the same error.
So I downloaded the certificates from the website on opening it in chrome. I downloaded all three certificates (for the root, intermediate and the website itself), and appended them to cacert.pem inside the certifi package folder. After that, when I ran it, OpenSSL was able to open it (and the requests library too, got a 200 response code). 
But, floobits still wasn't able to connect and gave the same error. I know that there is nothing wrong with floobits.com and the sublime extension since a friend can still open the workspace without problems.

Please tell me what I can do to fix this.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to describe exactly what you are doing to connect, which specific plugin you are using, the **full text** of the traceback you're getting, copied and pasted into your question, and the OS, Sublime, and plugin versions you're running. I would also suggest opening an issue with the plugin authors, giving them the same info.

Comment: From Sublime, open the Command Palette and run both `Package Control: Upgrade Package` (selecting the Floobits plugin if necessary) and `Package Control: Satisfy Dependencies`. This may help solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to 'solve' the problem by bringing Sublime back to a fresh state and then copying my files again. Answering here if anyone gets this problem.
Method:

1. Go to the Sublime > Preferences > Browse Packages
2. In this folder, copy and backup the 'User' folder to someplace else.
3. Delete all the folders in this location (Sublime need not be closed during this but it's best if you do close it)
4. Copy the backed-up 'User' folder back here (remember the location where you deleted, %AppData%\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages (for Windows))
5. All set, you now have a fresh installation of sublime.
6. Sublime will start installing all packages again, wait for it to finish and resume work.

This solved the problem I was having. Unfortunately, I couldn't track down the problem.